# Django-tables2 does not sort

Tags: django, django-tables2

I display a database table using django-tables2. All appears OK, but clicking on the column headers does not sort by that column. The headers are clickable, but  in their html has no url text in it, e.g.:

```
<div class="table-container">
<table class="paleblue"><thead><tr><th class="id orderable sortable"><a href="">ID</a>
</th><th class="orderable sortable system"><a href="">System</a></th> ...
```

I checked the django-tables2 template source and it sais this:

```
... <a href="{% querystring table.prefixed_order_by_field=column.order_by_alias.next %}"> ...
```

Which I do not understand.

I can only make sorting work by setting order_by in view.py:

```
class ResultsTable(tables.Table):
    class Meta:
        model = Performance
        attrs = {'class': 'paleblue'}
        order_by_field = True

def result(request, system):
    results = Performance.objects.filter(system__name=system)
    table = ResultsTable(results, order_by=('<any column name from Performance>',))
    RequestConfig(request).configure(table)
    return render_to_response('result.html', {'table': table})
```

but that obviously only works for one column and I want to click on columns to choose which one to sort by.

It is my understanding from the [docs](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) that sorting by column should work 'out of the box', is this correct, or am I doing something else wrong?

Comment: `order_by_field = True` here is not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer to my own question, after a night of sleep and a fresh look and word-by-word comparison of my code with the examples in the django-tables2 docs.

For the result function I used:

```
return render_to_response('result.html', {'table': table})
```

If I replace that with:

```
return render(request, 'result.html', {'table': table})
```

Sorting works as expected.
Don't ask me why...

Comment: Thanks Bradley. Django-tables2 is excellent by the way, exactly what I needed.

Comment: Bradley is right. To make your first example equivalent, you'd write `return render_to_response('result.html', {'table': table}, RequestContext(request))`

Answer (score 5):

Experienced the same issue, only I was missing the

```
django.core.context_processors.request
```

from TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS in settings.py

Comment: Thanks for inclusion. Had the same problem. This helped me, together with the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Other responses on this page point in the right direction, but just wanted to include everything required to get this working in one place. In the view:

1. Define your queryset *without* ordering
2. Pass the queryset into the table instance
3. Set any customizations on the table obj, like default ordering
4. Wrap it all in `RequestConfig` (essential - ordering won't work without this!)
5. Pass the fully-configured table into template context

```
# views.py
from django_tables2 import RequestConfig
...
data = MyModel.objects.all()
my_table = MySummariesTable(data)
my_table.order_by = "-name"
RequestConfig(request).configure(my_table)
ctx = {"my_table": my_table}

return render(request, "path/mytemplate.html", ctx)
```

If any of your columns need to be orderable by foreign-key relations, define those in your table column definitions with e.g.

```
col1 = tables.Column(verbose_name="Some Col", order_by="mycol.foobar.name")
```